# Blender built as a Python module, now how do I install and use it?

Tags: python

I built Blender as a Python module on Ubuntu 20.04.

The [installation instructions](https://wiki.blender.org/wiki/Building_Blender/Other/BlenderAsPyModule) are not very clear.

- I don't have a `/usr/lib/python3.7/site-packages` folder.
- When I run `make install` it says: `No rule to make target 'install'`

Answer (score 0):

Okay, I think I got it.

- cd to `~/blender-git/build_linux_bpy` and run make install
- this will install to a local path (`~/blender-git/lib/linux_centos7_x86_64/python/lib/python3.7/site-packages/2.91`)
- setting `WITH_INSTALL_PORTABLE=OFF` on the command line before the call to `make install` had no effect
- `~/blender-git/build_linux_bpy/CMakeCache.txt` defines the `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` variable
- I found this by running a search using `grep -rnw . -e 'PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES'`
- I set this `PYTHON_SITE_PACKAGES` to `/usr/lib/python3/dist-packages`
- I chose that path from the list returned by `python3 -m site`
- I can now import the bpy module from a python script

If anyone has a better way of doing this, let me know! Cheers.